# How to draw portion of pie image using canvas or Wedge shape in kinetic with touch event on iPad

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I use canvas or maybe Wedge shape in kinetic framework to load 2 circle image, 1 for image background, 1 for image percentage of pie. I bind touchstart, touchmove, touchend event for canvas container. Then i face 2 problem : first thing how to use canvas load a portion of circle image. For example : just load 1/4 of image circle. second thing is how to calculate portion of pie based on point of touch, when we touch down and move finger percentage of pie will increase and decrease as well.

please give me some suggestion or example. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to draw a wedge containing an image which changes based on clicks/taps**

[image]

For your inner “wedge”, you can use a Kinetic.Group object and use the clipFunc to crop an image into a wedge

Here’s the clipFunc for the image-wedge:

```
    clipFunc: function(canvas) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext();
        var w=wedgeWidth;
        var h=wedgeHeight;
        var r=wedgeRadius;
        var angle1=0; // start at vertical
        var angle2=angle1+radianAngle;
        ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
        ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,angle1,angle2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
```

radianAngle is the variable that controls the size of the wedge.

You can set the radianAngle (and the wedge size) like this:

```
// if the user clicks/taps on the stage
// redraw the image-wedge to the angle of the click/tap
function setRadianAngle(touchX,touchY){
    radianAngle=(Math.atan2(touchY-cy,touchX-cx)+Math.PI*2)%(Math.PI*2);
    layer.draw();
}
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/DxZLJ/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    enableStageClick();

    function enableStageClick(){
        $(stage.getContent()).on('click tap', function (event) {
            var pos=stage.getMousePosition();
            var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
            var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
            console.log(mouseX+"/"+mouseY);
            setRadianAngle(mouseX,mouseY);
        });
    }


  var wedgeWidth=300;
  var wedgeHeight=300;
  var wedgeRadius=100;
  var borderRadius=20;
  var radianAngle=135*Math.PI/180;
  var cx=wedgeWidth/2;
  var cy=wedgeHeight/2;

  // create the outside "border" circle
  var border = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: wedgeWidth/2,
    y: wedgeHeight/2,
    radius: wedgeRadius+borderRadius,
    fill:"skyblue",
    stroke: "blue",
    strokeWidth: 5
  });    
  layer.add(border);


  // create the inside "image-wedge" group
  var wedge=new Kinetic.Group({
      x:0,
      y:0,
      width:wedgeWidth,
      height:wedgeHeight,
      // clip to a wedge with angle==degreeAngle off vertical
      clipFunc: function(canvas) {
          var ctx = canvas.getContext();
          var w=wedgeWidth;
          var h=wedgeHeight;
          var r=wedgeRadius;
          var angle1=0; // start at vertical
          var angle2=angle1+radianAngle;
          ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
          ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,angle1,angle2,false);
          ctx.closePath();
      }
  });
  layer.add(wedge);

  // create the image that will be clipped inside the wedge
  var image=new Kinetic.Image({
      image:image,
      x:0,
      y:0,
      width:wedgeWidth,
      height:wedgeHeight,
  });
  wedge.add(image);

  // load the image for the Kinetic Image object
  var img=new Image();
  img.onload=function(){
      image.setImage(img);
      layer.draw();
  }
  img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolAidMan.png";


  // if the user clicks/taps on the stage
  // redraw the image-wedge to the angle of the click/tap
  function setRadianAngle(touchX,touchY){
      radianAngle=(Math.atan2(touchY-cy,touchX-cx)+Math.PI*2)%(Math.PI*2);
      layer.draw();
  }



}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <p>Click/Touch to change angle of wedge-image</p>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```